# How to change application theme while program is running in PyQt?

Tags: pyqt, pyqt5, pyqt4, pyqt6

I have an application in which there is a library of components, the styles of each component are set not in one place, but in the file of each component. For example, I have custom components Button, ToggleSwith, Select, Checkbox, I work with their styling and logic separately in their files. I want to implement in my application a theme change from light to dark and an accent color change. How can this be done at runtime? So that the user can choose a light or dark theme from the combobox and also an accent color, and they are immediately applied to all application components. I'm thinking about how to get the theme colors in the files of these components. And how to make it so that when they change, all components change based on the specified color or theme. QPallete or using environment variables comes to my mind, but I don't know how to implement it correctly.

Comment: You can set-up a top level qss string and replace it based on your theme.

Answer (score 0):

I have already implemented a dark/white switch in my application.

So you can simply change the stylesheet of the QApplication (meaning all windows).

For normal/bright design simply: `app.setStyleSheet('')`

And for dark design you either have to sit down for a few hours and make all things dark or copy it from someone who has already done it. (I have a link for you here, for the file I use: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/NiklasWyld/Wydbid/main/Assets/stylesheet)

You copy and paste that into app.setStyleSheet() or you make a file and read the contents of it into app.setStyleSheet().

Answer (score 0):

Came to your thread while i had a similar situation.
You can do dark/light switching with just a few lines and without defining dark mode all by yourself. Niklas Wilds app.setStyleSheet("") is part of this solution, check it out.

[Similar but more easy solution to that request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76521574/pyqt5-unable-to-pick-the-default-light-theme-when-switching-back-from-dark/76523536#76523536)