# Pyqt5 unable to pick the default light theme when switching back from dark

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface, pyqt5, themes, darkmode

When applying the dark theme and attempting to switch back to default, its some kind of other light theme for the whole ui.
While digging around i found app.style() returning a QCommonStyle object, so i imported it and tried using it, but the result can be seen in the screenshots below. I got similar results when using the "light" param using qdarktheme. I also tried saving the app.style() return value and giving it back when i want to switch, but traceback says that the object of QCommonStyle got deleted. Now im pretty much out of idea, especially after the QCommonStyle doesnt work like expected.

[Not the default theme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4xGW5.png)

[Indeed the default theme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uy4Nq.png)

```
app = QtWidgets.QApplication (sys.argv)
#qdarktheme.setup_theme ()
#qdarktheme.setup_theme ("light")
#qdarktheme.setup_theme ("auto")
#app.setStyle("Windows")
#app.setStyle(QCommonStyle())
ui = MainWindow ()
ui.show ()
app.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon('ippico.jpg'))
ui.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon('ippico.jpg'))
sys.exit (app.exec_ ())
```

EDIT:
In the meanwhile i figured out half the solution, but the ui does not update when switching to light.

```
def switch_theme(self):
  self.theme_switch = not self.theme_switch
  if self.theme_switch:
    logging.info("DARK")
    qdarktheme.setup_theme ()
  else:
    logging.info("BRIGHT")
    self.setStyleSheet ('')
```

It seems im missing some kind of trigger to finally update the shown ui.
Using pyqt5s update method doesnt work and setupUi simply breaks it.
I figured out taking away the stylesheet forces it to go back to the default design, but this only works before calling the show method right now. Any suggestion would be nice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved my problem - solution is below.
Most simple dark/light switch i could figure out.
After digging around in the qdarktheme module, i used the QCoreApplication with the setStyleSheet. There you go.

```
def switch_theme(self):
  self.theme_switch = not self.theme_switch
  if self.theme_switch:
    qdarktheme.setup_theme ()
  else:
    app = QCoreApplication.instance ()
    app.setStyleSheet ("")
```